# Kohana 3.2.0 + LINUX server - ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class not found

Tags: linux, kohana, classnotfoundexception

I'm running Kohana 3.2.0 and I have 2 systems; One Windows machine, and one Linux box

My Windows Machine:

- PHP Version 5.3.8
- Windows NT 6.1 build 7600 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition) i586

My Linux server:

- PHP Version 5.2.14-pl0-gentoo
- Linux ws2 2.6.16-gentoo-r1 #1 SMP Sun Apr 9 17:09:05 EEST 2006 i686

The Environment Tests - passed all (win and linux).

I`m getting an error on the Linux server:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_depoModel' not found
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/model.php [ 26 ]

public static function factory($name)
{
    // Add the model prefix
    $class = 'Model_'.$name;
    return new $class;
}
} // End Model
```

That's on the linux server

In the same time the same code on my win7 is running fine

The way I call the model:

```
public function action_project() {
   $news = Model::factory('depoModel');
   $news->vissu_projektu_izvade();
}
```

The Controler path = `\application\classes\controller`

Model path = `\application\classes\model`

In the model folder

file name = `depoModel.php`

in that file class def = `class Model_depoModel extends Model`

Where is the problem? Why is there an error on my Linux server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filenames should be in lowercase. Windows 7 is case insensitive, UNIX is case sensitive.